# My updateView creates a new post instead of updating the old post

Tags: python, django, django-views

My updateView creates a new post instead of updating the old post. i want to update my post but when i go to update form it creates a totally new post

> views.py

```
def edit_task(request, post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    form = TaskForm(instance=post)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('task')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'List/add_task.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the instance for GET requests and POST requests:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = TaskForm(request.POST, instance=post)
```

Comment: It's the code in `if request.method == 'POST'` that you need to change.

Comment: thanks alot it worked but when i edit the post it shows empty form why it dosent show the old post data

Comment: That's a separate problem, that I've answered on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62834707/how-can-i-prepopulate-this-update-form). It sounds like you changed the wrong line (when you said *I added request.POST*), and then never changed it back to `form = TaskForm(instance=post)`.